# Update a field for similar values in the second field based on third field value

Tags: python, arcpy

So I have the table like this:

```
City Distance NearFeature Comments
A    90.5     131025    
A    0        781446    
B    15.5     131057    
B    42.2     140521    
C    21.7     784116    
C    0        131025
```

Distance field contains distance value from the City to the NearFeature. Zero in the Distance field means that the City is completely inside the NearFeature.

What I want to accomplish is to populate the Comments field with the value from the NearFeature for Cities which are inside any NearFeature…. Like this:

```
City Distance NearFeature Comments
A    90.5     131025      City within 781446
A    0        781446      City within 781446
B    15.5     131057    
B    42.2     140521    
C    21.7     784116      City within 131025
C    0        131025      City within 131025
```

For B the Comments field is empty because it is outside any NearFeature.

Here is what I’ve done so far. This code updates the table, but only for rows which have 0 in the Distance field. What do I need to change to make it work in the way I need?

```
cities = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Path+"\\city.shp", "City")
citynames = []

with cities as rows:
    for row in rows:
        name = row[0]
        if name not in citynames:
            citynames.append(name)
del row, rows

fields = ["City", "Distance", "NearFeature", "Comments"]
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(Path+"\\city.shp", fields) as rows: 
    for row in rows:
        for i in citynames:
            if str(row[0]) in i and row[1] == 0:
                row[3] = 'City within '+ row[2]
                rows.updateRow(row)
del row, rows
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be solved with use of a dictionary object. Dictionaries let you associate a key value with another value. In the code below, I use your first cursor to associate the City value with the NearFeature value, if the Distance value is 0. I then use your second cursor to update the Comments field, if the value in the City field occurs in the dictionary.

```
cities = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Path+"\\city.shp", ["City", "Distance", "NearFeature"])
#Create empty dictionary
di = {}

with cities as rows:
    for row in rows:
        #Check if Distance is 0
        if row[1] == 0:
            #Add key as City and value as NearFeature
            di[row[0]] = row[2]
del row, rows

fields = ["City", "Comments"]
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(Path+"\\city.shp", fields) as rows: 
    for row in rows:
        #Check if City value is in dictionary
        if row[0] in di:
            row[1] = 'City within ' + str (di[row[0]])
            rows.updateRow(row)

del row, rows
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot Emil! I learn bit by bit every day...

Comment: Excellent. Keep on pythoning!